# Integral of Logistic Distribution

Tags: calculus

> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^x}{(1+e^x)^2} dx=0.$$

The integral represents the mean of the Logistic Distribution which is supposed to be zero. I've tried the following substitution:  $u=\frac{1}{1+e^x}, du=\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2} dx$ which gives:

> $$\int_{1}^0 \ln(\frac{1-u}{u}) du .$$

Integrating by parts then gives $u\ln(\frac{1}{u}-1)-\ln(1-u)$
But then substituting the limits of integration into the result would leave some terms undefined. Why isn't the result zero?

Comment: combine the ln terms. You will end up with some indeterminate forms on which LHospital can be used.

Comment: You need to use limit techniques to finish the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $u=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ we have
$$
x=\ln\frac{1-u}{u}=\ln(1-u)-\ln u,\quad \mathrm{d}u=-\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\mathrm{d}x,
$$
and therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\,dx&=&\int_0^1[\ln(1-u)-\ln u]\,du=\int_0^1\ln(1-u)\,du-\int_0^1\ln u\,du\\
&\stackrel{v=1-u}{=}&\int_0^1\ln v\,dv-\int_0^1\ln u\,du=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @LabBhattacharjee, thank you for the answer. I knew that you could use the "odd" function property to prove it. I was really trying to figure out how to compute the integral.

Comment: @EggHead: if what you wanted was the indefinite integral, why not ask for that instead?

Comment: @EggHead: note that this answer does not show how to compute the integral either. It is also a disguised version of the "odd function property" since $-x=\log\left(\frac{1-v}{v}\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle \text{If }f(x)=\frac{xe^x}{(e^x+1)^2},$

$\displaystyle f(-x)=\frac{-xe^{-x}}{(e^{-x}+1)^2}=-\frac{xe^x}{(e^x+1)^2}=-f(x)$

$\implies f(x)$ is odd function

Now use [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Odd_Function)

Comment: Your answer uses the oddness of the function in a more open manner than Mercy's. I like that (+1).

Comment: @robjohn, the integral represents the expected value of the Logistic Distribution which is supposed to be zero. The expected value of the Cauchy Distribution is given by the integral $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$  I'm not sure why the improper integral in this post exists but the integral for the Cauchy does not. Can you answer that on this post or did you want me to start another thread?

Comment: @EggHead: Not all distributions have a first moment that is well-defined. Even though $\frac1{1+x^2}$ is an even function, the integral of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ does not converge absolutely. In other contexts, one can use the Cauchy Principal Value to get a zero value for the integral of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. However, when dealing with random variables, this does not work since they are not assured to come evenly distributed. In this case, we really need absolute convergence of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Use instead the substitution $u=-x$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{ue^{-u}}{(1+e^{-u})^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{ue^u}{(1+e^u)^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
\end{align}
$$
Add the left side to both sides and divide by $2$.

---

Although the definite integral was requested, in a comment to lab bhattacharjee on Mercy's answer, it is mentioned that the indefinite integral was really sought. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{xe^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\frac{x}{(1+e^x)^2}\mathrm{d}e^x\\
&=-\int x\,\mathrm{d}\frac1{1+e^x}\\
&=-\frac{x}{1+e^x}+\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+e^x}\\
&=-\frac{x}{1+e^x}+\int\left(1-\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{x}{1+e^x}+x-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}e^x}{1+e^x}\\
&=\frac{xe^x}{1+e^x}-\log(1+e^x)+C
\end{align}
$$